# Data entry forms into multiple tables in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a data entry form bound to a query which has two tables with a left-to-right join (option 2 on join options).

The fields on the form are all bound to one of the fields from either table in the query.

My problem is that after I enter the data into the form and save it, the data from the right hand table will not show up on the query that the form is linked to, even though the data has been saved into the right hand table. The fields come up as blanks in the middle of fields that are filled. The fields from the left hand table are saved and appear, filled.

I need to be able to do this so that I can display the new data as a sub form in a different form.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: If the data is on the table it should be on the query. When you say "the data from the right hand table will not show up on the query" are you testing the actual query or just the bound form?